# Why is there no on/off button for irons?

Tags: design

I've never seen any iron have an on/off button. So my guess is that most of them do not have one. Is there any specific reason for that?

Comment: Preventing errors is the right answer and even though it is not a direct duplicate, it has been indeed answered in the question mentioned by @Awesh.

Comment: Marked as a duplicate because, although the specific product may be different, the overall reasoning is the same.